# Applying for a new UK visa before old one expires

Tags: visas

I've applied for Tier 5 (Youth Mobility) visa for the UK but my Tier 4 student visa is still valid. If my new visa application is unsuccessful, could I still enter the UK with my current Tier 4 to complete my course? The Tier 4 visa expires in January 2018.

Answer (score 1):

Legally speaking, this is called a change of an immigration status: you replace one visa with another. You can and usually have to do this while you have a valid visa.

If you Tier 5 visa application will be denied, that does not mean your student visa will be canceled, so you will be able to come to the UK continue your studies.

Comment: I don't think this is a change of immigration status because it is being done from outside the UK.